# Davening in Open Orthodox Shul

Tags: halacha, synagogue, conservative-judaism

Although there may be a wide range of Open Orthodox shuls, may one daven in an Open Orthodox shul if a woman leads as the chazan for shacharis or ba'al koreh? Would such an Open Orthodox shul have the same halachic status as Conservative, which Rav Moshe Igros Moshe (EH 2:17) forbade davening inside? What about merely entering for a bar mitzvah without davening?

Comment: I think you should realize that "Open Orthodoxy" isn't a well defined movement with centralized rulings. There's plenty of variation in that space between Orthodox and Conservative. If you don't really know what happens in Shuls that identify as Open Orthodox, maybe you shouldn't conflate them with the rumors. Either ask about OO Shuls or ask about Shuls that follow the practices described in those rumors.

Comment: It appears that you are conflating OO with Shira Chadashah/partnership minyanim. The two are not specifically mutually inclusive terms.

Comment: I must REALLY be out of the "loop". What is Open Orthodoxy? This is the first time I'm reading this term.

Comment: FWIW I don't think the most recent edit (which was described as "More accurately asked what was being requested") doesn't do what it described. It provides extra motivation for the question, but doesn't help define what is being asked.

Comment: OO does not accept that a woman can daven before the 'amud for shacharis/musaf, nor do partnership minyanim, who permit women to lead parts of tefillah and lein. As a general rule, while they are generally meikil, OO rabbis are careful to stay within the bounds of Orthodox halacha l'ma'aseh

Comment: @Noach Leining and Aliyot being the major exception thereof where the Talmud and traditional Halakha clearly prohibits it. You're right though about the Sha"tz issues AFAIK; they only allow women to do "meaningless" things like Pesukei DiZimra.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I thought a woman could lein (ergo receive 'aliyot, due to the understanding of Chaza"l). The minyanim with whom I daven don't let women lein or receive 'aliyot, although many do have at least some OO presence.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt I'm not sure what you're asking. The Talmud and traditional Halakha clearly prohibit women from doing those things, but in that regard some OO-leaning folks at least break their general policy of being careful to stay within the bounds of Orthodox halacha l'ma'aseh.

Answer (score -1):

Your description of what "Open Orthodoxy" does means that it is no different from the Conservative movement. You have stated that the baal koreh or baal tefilah can be women. As [Rabbi Avi Shafran](http://rabbiavishafran.com/) explains in [Denominational Déjà Vu](http://jewishweek.timesofisrael.com/denominational-deja-vu/) the movement appears to be on the same path that the "Conservative" movement has already traveled.

As a result, the halacha would appear to be the same as the original psak on that movement (even before it reached its current status).

> I perceive precisely the same Conservative approach to halacha in what
>   bills itself today as “Open Orthodoxy.”
>
> Whether the halachic topic being addressed is same-sex relationships,
>   interfaith interactions, kashrut, marriage, divorce or conversion, the
>   desideratum of “Open Orthodoxy” is unmistakably to bring Jewish
>   religious praxis “into line” with contemporary mores. That may not be
>   explicit in the wording of “Open Orthodox” statements or responsa —
>   any more than it was 14 years ago in those of the Conservative
>   movement. But in both cases it is manifest.

...

> Let me stress that I am speaking of a concept here, not people; of
>   theological systems, not the intentions of students who have been
>   attracted to “Open Orthodox” institutions, some of whom are clearly
>   idealists who wish to serve the Jewish people. The problem isn’t those
>   students or their idealism, but rather the proposition they are
>   taught, that halacha is ripe for “updating.”

...

> The new movement’s name is a misnomer, a dangerously misleading one.
>   Just as “kosher-style” food isn’t kosher, neither is “Open Orthodoxy”
>   Orthodox. It is neo-Conservatism. Which is why the greatest, most
>   widely recognized, Torah scholars today — and not only those of the
>   charedi world — have rejected its Jewish authenticity.
>
> I take no pleasure in revealing the truth about “Open Orthodoxy.” But
>   truth-in-labeling is not only a civil mandate but a halachic one.

Comment: "Your definition of what 'Open Orthodoxy' does means that it is no different from the Conservative movement." Is that so? Is having women read Torah the only meaningful difference between the Orthodox and Conservative movements? That's baloney and I think you know it. There are ideological and theological differences that would seem to be much more relevant.

Comment: @DoubleAA Rabbi Shafran points out that the difference in this case shows that the basic philosophy behind the movement is the same as the philosophy that led the Conservative movement down the path that it has followed. His point was that it is going down the same path, but farther behind.

Comment: If only life was as simplistic as R Shafran thinks... We all know that there are lots of paths that can be similar in some ways and different in others. It's not black and white ("reform path" vs "orthodox path"). We should strive to identify issues and Psakim more precisely and not slander thousands of Jews through sheer laziness at not wanting to dig deeper than these generalities.

Comment: @DoubleAA The description as given in the question (*have women lead shacharis and musaf*) would mean that it would fall into the parameters of Rav Moshe's psak. If the term used *Open Orthodoxy* is incorrect then that should be corrected. I will add this to the answer.

Comment: "would mean that it would fall into the parameters of Rav Moshe's psak" How do you know that? What are the parameters of R Moshe's psak? You should include those and show how this fits in.

Comment: Even if your claim that Open Orthodoxy is on the same path the Conservative Movement took is true, how does it follow that a ruling about the Conservative movement should apply to Open Orthodoxy _before_ OO reaches as far along the path as Conservative has?

Comment: @Daniel The claim appears tobe (by those making it) that the movement has traveled far enough along the path as to merit the inclusion based on how far the Conservative movement had gone at the time Rav Moshe made his psak. In this case, the OP had included having women daven from the amud.